# AJAX Post Successful but PHP not responding

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm having trouble with an AJAX POST to PHP call.

JS in an PHP file (tableOutput.php)

```
var changedArr=[];
var undoRedoArr=[];

//For editing data, http://tabulator.info/docs/3.3
$("#tabulator").tabulator({
     cellEdited:function(cell){
    //this is called whenever a cell's value is edited.
      var value = cell.getValue();
      var theID = cell.getRow().getIndex();
      var ip=cell.getRow().getData();
      var field = cell.getField();
      var x=Object.values(ip);
      console.log(ip);
      changedArr.push(x);
      },
});

//called when I hit a button
function saveChanges(){
       $.ajax({
         url: "getInfo.php/",
         type:'POST',
         data: {'ipString':changedArr},
         success: function(){
            alert("SAVED!");
         },
         error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, error){
            alert("AJAX error: " + textStatus + "; " + error);
         }
       })
   console.log(changedArr);
}

</script>

<?php
   include "getInfo.php";
?>
```

PHP code in a different file (getInfo.php)

```
<?php
 if(!empty($_POST['ipString'])){
   echo '<script language="javascript">';
   echo 'alert("Post")';
   echo '</script>';
 }

 if(!empty($_REQUEST['ipString'])){
   echo '<script language="javascript">';
   echo 'alert("Request")';
   echo '</script>';
 }

?>
<html>
  <head>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
</html>
```

Earlier in the files, I have a GET command that works.

HTML in tableOutput.php

```
<div class=form>
  <form onsubmit="fillTable()" >
     <input type="submit" name="deny" value="Denied" />
     <input type="submit" name="permit" value="Permitted" />
  </form>
</div>
```

getInfo.php

```
$test="'CREATE'";
if( isset( $_GET['deny'] )){
  $test="'DENY'";
}
if( isset( $_GET['permit'] )){
  $test="'CREATE'";
}
```

Tried on Fedora and Windows. Code is on a server. Browser: Firefox

The Ajax posts successfully. I get an alert box saving "SAVED!", but nothing echos on the page. If I use window.location.href instead, then the getInfo.php echos to the page. The problem is that I get redirected to the getInfo.php page, which I don't want.

How do I get the Ajax to post to the getInfo.php file? Why is it not working?

Comment: Why is there a trailing slash in `url: "getInfo.php/",`?

Comment: Put an echo outside the if-statements in your PHP file to make sure it answers. It is likely not entering the if-statements.

Comment: @ChrisForrence, I don't remember why the slash is there. I deleted it.

Comment: @Daniel, There are separate echos outside the if-statements that work with tableOut.php, and also separate ones that work on their own. When I add " echo $_REQUEST['ipString'];" the page prints out "Notice: Undefined index: ipString in /getInfo.php on line 113", even after I hit the save button. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Just did. Nothing different seemed to happen. I could be missing something.

Comment: Take that getinfo include out. You will not make any changes with Ajax. That happens on the server side. Look at @Matt Spink's answer. See how he catches the response in the success stage. There is too much wrong in the code at this stage to give you a complete answer. First send teh request to a php and have it echo something back. That is the loop you must go for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not with the code posted. 
At the beginning of getInfo.php, I forgot to add "php"
It was:

```
<?
```

instead of:

```
<?php
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to mix two different mechanisms here (AJAX and post-back). When you use AJAX, simply `echo`-ing output will not insert that content into the DOM (like it does when using a full post-back). Your `echo` statement puts data into the output stream that is then consumed by your `success` function. And it will stay there unless you programmatically (using javascript/jQuery) insert it into the DOM. You can manually insert that into the DOM. There are many ways of doing that. The key is looking at your response object. This is one possibility:

```
function saveChanges(){
       $.ajax({
         url: "getInfo.php/",
         type:'POST',
         data: {'ipString':changedArr},
         success: function(response){
            alert("SAVED!");
            //add the script element to the DOM body
            $(response).appendTo('body');
         },
         error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, error){
            alert("AJAX error: " + textStatus + "; " + error);
         }
       })
   console.log(changedArr);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is important to understand that when including a php file (like *getInfo.php*), the output is written on the client side and cannot be accessed by php anymore.

What you want is to request the getInfo.php, get its response the write it on the client side.

Client:

```
<script>
    function saveChanges(){
       $.ajax({
         url: "getInfo.php/",
         type:'POST',
         data: {'ipString':changedArr},
         success: function(textResponse /* you MUST use this parameter*/){
            alert("SAVED!");
            // textResponse is the string the server sends. do whatever you want with this
            document.getELementById("out").innerHTML = textResponse;
         },
         error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, error){
            alert("AJAX error: " + textStatus + "; " + error);
         }
       })
   console.log(changedArr);
}
</script>

<div id="out"></div>
```

At the server side, it is important you do not include any `<head>` or `<body>` tags, otherwise you will have a new document inside your `<div id="out"></div>`! You should write just pure text, or something that can be put inside a div element, like a table.

Server: getInfo.php

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['ipString'])) {
    echo "A request has been made"; 
}
?>
```

or write pure html closing the php tags (a nice trick):

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['ipString'])) {
    ?>
    A request has been made
    <?php
}
?>
```

If your *getInfo.php* file needs to have its `<head>` and `<body>` tags, you must `exit()` the script so the rest of the file will not be sent.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['ipString'])) {
    echo "A request has been made"; 
    exit(); // exit here so ajax doesn't get the rest of the file
}
?>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body></body>
</html>
```

Finally, if you want to be flexible and have your client do stuff based on what the server sends, you should try **JSON** which converts objects to strings and vice versa.